# angular 4 submit a request to the external application and call back to the angular application

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 4, I would like to send/post details to the external application just like payment processing after checkout in amazon. Let us say after adding items to the cart in angular, would like to submit for payment processing to the external application(i.e., the current angular application should be redirected to payment application) and once payment is success it should redirect back to angular application with transaction id and success message. How to achieve this in angular.

Here is a sample code.

I have a angular component template and onclick it is submitting the request to paypal and the UI is redirected to paypal site and payment is success it redirects to http://localhost:4200/ordersuccess and in this component I would like to read the properties/request parameters sent by the paypal like transactionid, message etc.

```
<form #form method="post" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" >

  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Paypal demo charge">
  <input name="item_number" type="hidden" value="0001"/>

  <input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://localhost:4200/ordersuccess" />
  <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="https://localhost:4200/orderfailure" />
  <input type="hidden" name="custom" value={{title}}>

  <input (click)="form.submit()" type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0"
         name="submit" />
</form>


// ordersuccess.component.ts

export class ordersuccess implements oninit{

ngOninit(){

// would like to retrieve request parameters sent by paypal using post request. 

}


}
```

Thanks,
Hari.

Comment: please provide some code

Comment: it is similar to this  https://github.com/musale/angular2-paypal. I submit to it and after payment it has to redirect to angular app with transaction id,message and angular should be able to retrieve it.

Comment: please try with the callback that i provided

Answer (score 0):

you can do callback like this.

**callback function**

```
callBackFunction(callback: (model: any) => void): any {
    isConfirmed=someCallBackValue   
        callback(isConfirmed);
  }
```

**calling callback funvtion**

```
  this.callBackFunction((callBackRes) => {
      console.log("this is the responce of call back function "+ callBackRes);
  })
```

Comment: I really dont know how to use call back function. When the angular application is redirected to paypal and after payment it has to redirect to the angular app and i need to read the values like transaction id and messages if any etc.

Comment: then please provide some code of that. then i'll explain with that

Comment: updated my post with code. please have a look. Thanks.